.NET microservices on AWS ECS with inter-service communication using service connect grpc
I am using AWS ECS to host my microservices project, for interservice communication I want to use grpc and service connect.
the issues I am facing is that gRPC works using SSL and I am not able to understand where can I set this SSL. Do I have to enable encryption on service connect level or it should work as it is without SSL?
please share examples on how you are achieving interservice communication using AWS ecs service connect feature.
